# Batch file to Zip file

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I am new to programming, thanks to the new task my boss has provided.
I am trying to run a batch file to zip multiple files in a folder separately.
So, I want file1.txt to zip to file1.zip and so on for other files.

I have only the following code:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /b *.DAT') do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%f.7z" "%f"
```

My issue: When I run it on cmd after navigating to the target folder, it works, but when I store it in a batch file and run it from the target folder, it wont work.

Please help me identify what and where I need to make changes in my code.

Regards
AK

Comment: You've already covered the "hard part" - finding a cmd-line tool to .zip a file: `"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"`.  Q: Is your .bat file actually running in the same directory as your *.dat files?  If not, you might put a `cd \my directory` at the top of the .bat file.

Comment: Yes, the batch file is in the same dir.

Answer (score 3):

WIthin a batch file, the metavariable (loop-control variable) requires the `%` to be doubled, so replace each `%f` with `%%f` when you mean `the loop-control variable`"f"`

Comment: Hi @Magoo, I just wanted to know if I can tweak my code a bit, so that my file "abc.txt" renamed to abc.zip instead of abc.txt.zip? I would appreciate your help on this. Here's the code:@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET old=abc_1
SET new=abc
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.DAT') do (
  SET newname=%%f
  SET newname=!newname:%old%=%new%!
  move "%%f" "!newname!"
)

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.DAT') do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%f.7z" "%%f"

Comment: if your filename is in `%%f` then `%%~nf` will give you the name-part of the file and `%%~xf` the extension-part, so a target name `%%~nf.zip` will put the name-part (`abc` of `abc.txt`) together with `.zip`

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine. The issue is, that when you run it inside a batch file, you need to put an extra % mark.

In the batch try:

```
 for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.DAT') do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%f.7z" "%%f"
```